# How to use C# conditional compilation preprocessors to resolve same class name in a namespace complication error?

Tags: c#, .net

I usually use some helper classes in my projects that I write for an online contest. As I should send each answer for each question in a form of a single .cs file, these classes will be repeated in each file. also I want to have only one project for each contest (containing all answers files) so I won't get lost in projects folders scrolling all the time wasting seconds. (otherwise I would create a single library which has the common helper classes and referenced that dll to this project using it in all many files that I have, or just create one project per each question).

**File1.cs**

```
namespace MyProject
{
    // The code for question 1
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {

    }
}
```

**File2.cs**

```
namespace MyProject
{
    // The code for question 2
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {

    }
}
```

**The compiler error**

```
The namespace 'MyNamespace' already contains a definition for 'MyClass'
```

My question is how to suppress the compiler so it doesn't compile same class in same namespace in all files over and over again?
Maybe define an #if #endif block somehow?!

Also if there is another approach other than using preprocessors to repeating blocks of code, without getting compilation errors, it would be nice.

P.S. The reason behind not wanting to create multiple projects is also comes down to the way I want to unit test these files.

**Edit**
the goal here is to be able to have multiple instances of the same namespace `MyNamespace` identical to one another repeated in source code but only be compiled once. if we compile only one of this files separately then the namespace would be compiled correctly but if the files get compiled together only one of the instances be visible to the compiler so we don't get error.

Comment: Make the classes `partial`, or give one of them a different name.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn What would be the difference? the properties and methods will get the compilation errors because they are already defined in previous files identically.

Comment: That is true: partial will only help if the classes are different. Guess you'll need to give them different names.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ yeah, thank you. I'm aware of that but I want same namespace repeated on multiple files but complied one time only. I don't think partial classes would work

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I hope I find something so I wouldn't have to change the names, but thank you

Comment: What's the reason to use the same namespace and same class name? Why can't you change one or another?

Comment: @Magnetron because I copy and past all of the helper classes that I wrote before into the file that I want to upload each time and I want to be as fast as I can.

Comment: All I'm reading is that you're trying to go through a great deal of trouble just to avoid doing a `copy assignment4.cs+helperclasses.cs submitassignment4.cs`. If you don't like manual copying, you can even just make this a post-build step. Since you're not going to be submitting the project itself as the assignment, you should view the source as a build artifact.

Comment: I'm only allowed to upload one file and that's the problem, If I could have helperclasses.cs that would solve the problem asap. but I think you're probably right about the cost-benefit of the whole thing. @JeroenMostert

Comment: My point is that the file you will upload can simply be generated by a build step, batch file, PowerShell script or what have you from a more "sane" project that has one single, proper `helperclasses.cs` the way you'd normally write it. The fact that you ultimately have to submit one file should not constrain the way you develop that file. In other words: the file you're going to submit doesn't have to be the file(s) you're compiling locally.

Comment: your are absolutely correct I should write a build command so it would generate the file, the up side of this approach is that there will be only one `helperclass.cs` that could the clear the files that I'm working on, and one source of truth that could be edited anytime. thanks for the insight.